# Google Sheets: Dynamic ImportXML Formula

Tags: xml, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula in cell H12 that I’m trying to use. The formula is as follows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F12:F), INDEX(IMPORTXML(“https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/” &F12:F, “//span[@class=‘def’]”), MATCH(F12:F,F12:F,0)), “”))
```

It’s kind of working, but it’s returning the definition of the first word in the first row of column F for all rows that have a word in them. In this case, it’s F12.

My goal is to display the definition of each unique word in each row of column F12:F dynamically using only one formula. I hope you can help me with this. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much and have a blessed day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(F12:F,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join("",index(importxml("https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/"&Σ, "//span[@class='def']"),1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @rockinfreakshow ! I hope this message finds you well. I wanted to let you know that the formula you provided is working splendidly. However, I did come across an error message with some words that stated — Loading data may take a while because of the large number of requests. Try to reduce the amount of IMPORTHTML, IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED or IMPORTXML functions across spreadsheets you’ve created. — (1 of 2)

Comment: I have a feeling that this might be due to having more than 100 words in column F, but I’m not entirely sure. Despite this, I’m over the moon that it’s working! If it’s not too much bother, would you mind sharing your thoughts on why this error might be occurring? Do you think that other external worksheets in my Google Drive containing the ImportXML formula could be adding to the delay in the requests? Once again, thank you ever so much for all your help! Wishing you all the best and continued success. And please accept my apologies for my delayed response. (2 of 2)